# React components always return the first code

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I have an chat application that requires authentication. Uses cookies. Here what I try:

```
class AppHeader extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }
    render() {
        if (cookies.get('token') !== undefined || cookies.get('token') !== '') {
            return (<div className={styles.container}>
                <button onClick={this.stravante}>[ Logout ]</button>
            </div>)
        } else {
            return (<div></div>)
        }
    }
}
```

It always return:

[image]

even if the cookie `token` is empty or undefined.
I have trying many ways, like using state.

Comment: What happens if you do `console.log(cookies.get('token').length)` when user is supposed to be logged out? It should return 0 — if not, you have a space in there that makes it return true.

Comment: no, I can also see the cookies on the Application panel

Comment: `if (!cookies.get('token'))` It will also work as you are only checking `''` and `undefined` and they are falsy, in my opinion this if will be enough to check for this condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript undefined and '' both are falsy value. no need to check explicitly.
Change your if condition if (cookies.get('token') !== undefined || cookies.get('token') !== '') to if (cookies.get('token'))

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which library you're using for `cookies` but in javascript you'll find that `undefined !== ''`. so if `cookies.get('token')` is `undefined` then `cookies.get('token') !== ''` will always be `true`.

Easiest fix is to make that an `&&`, eg:

```
const tokenCookie = cookies.get('token');
if (tokenCookie !== undefined && tokenCookie !== '') {
  return (<div className={styles.container}>
    <button onClick={this.stravante}>[ Logout ]</button>
   </div>);
} else {
  return (<div></div>)
}
```